# Accessing Object of Object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, object

I'm trying to access and process the response of an API call in this form:

```
{ BTC: { available: '0.77206464', onOrder: '0.00177975' },
  LTC: { available: '0.00000000', onOrder: '0.00000000' },
  ETH: { available: '1.14109900', onOrder: '0.00000000' },
  BNC: { available: '0.00000000', onOrder: '0.00000000' },
  MTL: { available: '0.00000000', onOrder: '0.00000000' },
  SALT: { available: '0.00000000', onOrder: '0.00000000' },
  NULS: { available: '0.00000000', onOrder: '0.00000000' } }
```

I'm using js and node for the backend server and ejs as templating.

Trying to iterate over this object always get me something like

```
BTC [object Object] LTC [object Object]
```

Anyone could help me? Thanks in advance

Comment: What are you _expecting_?

Comment: Help you what? Dot or bracket notation should do the job just fine.

Comment: "Trying to iterate over this object" - we don't know what this means. Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) especially the [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You haven't showed us the code you're using to iterate and work with the items. You're likely doing a for/in and alerting or dumping to screen the top level key/values--treating them as strings. So you're seeing the key, and the string conversion of the object in the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might be looking for that.

```js
var objOfobj = { BTC: { available: '0.77206464', onOrder: '0.00177975' },
  LTC: { available: '0.00000000', onOrder: '0.00000000' },
  ETH: { available: '1.14109900', onOrder: '0.00000000' },
  BNC: { available: '0.00000000', onOrder: '0.00000000' },
  MTL: { available: '0.00000000', onOrder: '0.00000000' },
  SALT: { available: '0.00000000', onOrder: '0.00000000' },
  NULS: { available: '0.00000000', onOrder: '0.00000000' }  
}
  
  

for (const property in objOfobj) {
  console.log(`${property}: ${objOfobj[property].available}`);
  console.log(`${property}: ${objOfobj[property].onOrder}`);
}
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks. One question what is the ` used for?

Comment: I'm glad my answer solved you problem, do not forget to validate to let the community know that your problem is solved.

Comment: The ` is a syntax to use  variable with ${} directly in a string. If you prefer use `console.log(property + " : " + objOfobj[property].onOrder)`